# Is using ISO-8601 date strings to compare against a DateField in Django's ORM officially supported and portable?

Tags: django, date, django-models, orm

It seems that with Django's ORM I can consistently use an ISO-8601 date string instead of a `datetime.date` when querying against a model's `DateField`.  For example, if I have a model like:

```
from django.db import models

class Sitting(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

Then in my experience queries like the following work fine:

```
Sitting.objects.filter(start_date='2015-12-25')
Sitting.objects.filter(start_date__gte='2016-01-01')
```

... as well as:

```
Sitting.objects.filter(start_date=datetime.date(2015, 12, 25))
Sitting.objects.filter(start_date__gte=datetime.date(2016, 1, 1))
```

My questions are:

- Is this officially supported, or might there be some underlying database for which using ISO-8601 strings doesn't work?
- I might well be missing something obvious, I couldn't find this documented anywhere - is there somewhere in the Django documentation that describes how values used in queries against `DateField` fields are used?

Comment: See this code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/utils/dateparse/#parse_date

Comment: @RadosławGanczarek: ah, right - and I see that's used in `DateField.to_python`, which is used in `get_prep_value`... Thanks!

Comment: This isn't just a `DateField` thing, All django model fields (that I can think of) use the `to_python` (as you've seen) to try to cast the value such that `myint='1'` would also work for an [IntegerField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1841) etc.